# Why is the magnetic force on a current-carrying wire sometimes called the Laplace force?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, electricity

Educated in the UK, I've been used to calling the force on a current-carrying wire in a magnetic field 'the *motor effect* force'. But I'm increasingly aware of another (less clumsy?) name for it: 'the *Laplace* force'. Less clumsy, maybe; but is the name justified? What role did Laplace play in investigating or analysing these forces?

Comment: Hypothesis: It might be related to Laplace pressure formula and his work on surface tension as the soap bubble rail experiment is pretty similar to the electromagnetic one https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rail_gun.jpg and https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Surface-tension-measurement-device.svg

Comment: In French many formulas change names to give credit to French scientists: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_de_Laplace

Comment: Laplace was credited by Biot and Ampere with help in designing and analyzing their experiments. Some details are in https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf but nothing on the force $BIL$ on current-carrying wire. Maybe it's just French naming things after French scientists, but the name is very useful for making a distinction from the Lorentz force, which came much later.